# Javascript Stack and Canvas / WebGl or Qt and C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, canvas, webgl

I want to create a small desktop application and have some problems to decide which way to go.
There will be up to 5000 2D elements in the view with blending and so on.
Also zooming will be needed.

To make this app cross platform and cause I like Javascript, CSS and Html I would like to use Electron and then use Canvas or WebGl.
But I don't have any experience in terms of the performance.

Alternative would be C++ and the Qt-Library. But I would prefer the Electron way.

Does anyone have some experience concerning the performance of WebGl and Canvas?

Comment: From experience, WebGL on desktop will easily handle 5000 2D elements. Pixi.js is a good choice for webgl/canvas rendering of 2D and, for me, this performance test shows no slow down with 5000 sprites: http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/.

Comment: Thank you for this demo. Looks really good. Do you know how far WebGl is comparable with OpenGl?

Comment: WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0. Here are the specs: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/ and a handy reference card (https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf). There are limitations in what you can do but I've not really come up against them while working on 2D projects.

Comment: Okay thank you. What about sharp scalable vector graphics? Is WebGL also the best solution?

Comment: That probably is the biggest limitation with WebGL, if you look at that Pixi.js framework there is a graphics class that draws primitive shapes but, as those shapes get complicated, you could end up with a lot of triangles being drawn on the gpu. You could upload svg as a texture but it will be rasterized. You could always layer a webgl canvas with html/svg for UI elements but that might have some performance implications and add complexity to the project.

Comment: How are big applications like Photoshop or Illustrator render their graphics? Do you know if OpenGL is better suited for vector graphics?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103074/discussion-between-brettjephson-and-manu).